# C++ copy string to clipboard for linux

Tags: c++, linux, clipboard

I want to copy a string to clipboard, after it being generated randomly. I could find the windows way of doing it (Windows.h) but how can I do it for linux?

An extract of my code:

```
void generate_and_copy_to_clipboard() {
    std::string output = "some-generate-string";
    // how can I copy `output` into the clipboard?
}
```

Comment: which windowing manager are You using?

Comment: terminal, it's not gui (I am using wsl, do I have to use a desktop environment?)

Comment: In case your window manager use GTK, you may take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204996/how-do-i-use-clipboard-in-gtk). And in case of Qt, take a look at [this](https://github.com/Arian8j2/ClipboardXX/blob/44b74b296642cf00eeaa4b7d3440b6688c25f2db/include/ClipboardXX.hpp#L88)

Comment: Basically, copy [xclip.c](https://github.com/milki/xclip/blob/master/xclip.c#L275). I would go with `popen("xclip -sel clip"` and just writing data there - the end.

Comment: But that's in  C... (and I don't really understand C)

Comment: it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436257/how-do-you-copy-paste-from-the-clipboard-in-c

Comment: You could use a cross-platform library like [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) which provides [clipboard functionality](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html#clipboard) among many other features.

Comment: Hi, I could not compile in visual studio: `unresolved external symbol glfwSetClipboardString referenced in function "void __cdecl generate(void)" (?generate@@YAXXZ)`